# Having trouble using an STL map's iterator while removing elements

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, iterator

I'm looping through an STL map to delete elements and do some clean up.  Unfortunately for me  my program crashes on the ++iter line.  Am I doing something wrong in how I'm looping over the map?

```
std::map<string,BoneHierarchy* >::iterator iter = boneMap.begin();
while(iter != boneMap.end()) {
    string playerName = iter->first;
    boneMap[playerName]->clear();
    boneQueue->push(boneMap[playerName]);
    boneMap.erase(iter);
    ++iter;
}
```

Comment: I think iterators should only read/modify, when you delete it the iteration in progress is broken.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6438086/893693

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't increment the iterator after deleting it (it's been erased, so how can you expect to increment it?). Erase a copy of the iterator with:

```
boneMap.erase(iter++);
```

or do

```
iter = boneMap.erase(iter);
```

if using C++11.

(See also [Removing elements from a C++ map through a for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191644/removing-elements-from-a-c-map-through-a-for-loop))

Answer (score 3):

```
boneMap.erase(iter);
++iter;                     //incorrect
```

should be written as:

```
iter = boneMap.erase(iter); //correct (in C++11)
//no need to increment!
```

Because [`map::erase()` returns iterator following the erased item](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase).

Comment: `map::erase(iterator position)` returns `void`.

Comment: @jpm: It doesn't exist anymore (in C++11). In C++11, it returns iterator.

Comment: Neat, I wasn't familiar with that update. Thanks for the info. Also, +1.