# How to insert data into map where one parameter is an object?

Tags: c++, stl

I have a class Normal defined as:

```
    class Normal
    {
        bool value;
        float time;
        public:
            Normal(bool val,float time): value(val),time(time) {}
    }
```

Also, I have declared a map variable as:

```
    map<string,Normal> myMap;
```

Now I want to insert an data into this map.
Is this way of inserting correct?

```
    Normal temp(true,45.04);
    myMap.insert(pair<string,Normal>("one",temp));
```

or

```
    myMap["one"]=temp;
```

How should i insert data into the map?

Comment: Any reason forbids you from using `map<string, Normal>`?

Comment: `Normal*` is a pointer. `temp` isn't one. Do you really want your map to contain pointers?

Comment: I have changed it to `Normal`.So now what is the correct way of inserting data?

Comment: Maybe read this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map and see the semantic differences between `insert` and `operator[]`. And figure out which one of the two you need.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use this code

```
Normal *temp =  new Normal(true,45.9);
mymap.insert(make_pair("one",temp));
```

avoid shallow copy since pointer is involved.

EDIT: Use insert function to insert data in map. Index is not the best way. specially when u r accessing
See this link for details 
[In STL maps, is it better to use map::insert than []?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326062/in-stl-maps-is-it-better-to-use-mapinsert-than)

EDIT2: For deletion,use the below code.

```
for(std::map<string, Normal*>::iterator itr = mymap.begin();it !=  mymap.end();)
{
  if(it->second != NULL)
   {
      delete (it->second);
      (it->second) = NULL;
      it=mymap.erase(it);
    }
    else
    {
         ++it;
    }

  }
```

Comment: There's nothing in OP's code that suggests they need dynamic allocation (not even before the edit.) A pointer does not automatically mean dynamic allocation.

Comment: @juanchopanza : i fully agree with you. But if you are using pointer, your better off creating dynamic ones. I prefer it that way. :)

Comment: @juanchopanza : Can you please explain in detail with an example. It will help me a lot.

Comment: @Spanky you are not deleting the element from map, just updating the elem.second as null after deleting the elem.second. Map size will not change after your deletion.

Comment: @Steephen : yeah!!! thats a good point. Edited the code to add erase. 1 Question here...mymap.clear(), will it not remove all the entries?

Comment: @Spanky it will clear the map and lose all of the pointers. Leak !

Comment: Your usage of erase is wrong, it will invalidate iterator. map::clear() is going to remove all elements from map. did you test your code?

Comment: @Steephen : if I delete the pointer and then clear the map as I have done above. Then there should not be any leak. Am I correct? ignore the erase for a moment.

Comment: @Spanky No. When you clear you are going to loose all elements of map not only the one you deleted.

Comment: @Steephen: So erase should be better option. my code should free the pointer and then erase the element. clear should not be done at all. correct?

Comment: You should use erase properly, and clear is not needed to delete an element from a map.

Comment: @Steephen : Ok!! thanks a lot. good learning for me. Is the erase I have written is wrong? If yes , then can you just write the erase properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80036/discussion-between-spanky-and-steephen).

Comment: This URL may help you to understand  more details :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191644/removing-elements-from-a-c-map-through-a-for-loop

Answer (score 4):

In C++03 :

```
myMap.insert(std::make_pair(
    "one",
    Normal(true, 45.04)
));
```

In C++11 :

```
m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
          std::forward_as_tuple("one"),
          std::forward_as_tuple(true, 45.04)
);
```

Both avoid default-constructing a key-value pair inside `operator[]` and then overwriting it.